# How do I add a custom method to a restangular service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, restangular

I have a decoupled Restangular service which I'd like to attach a custom method to. It appears that the only methods returned on a collection by default are `getList`, `one`, and `post`. I would like to do `Locations.getLongLat()`

I have tried adding the following to my service with no luck (the method isn't bound to the object) and I just get `undefined is not an object` in response.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('Locations', function (Restangular) {

    return Restangular.withConfig(function (RestangularConfigurer) {
        RestangularConfigurer.addElementTransformer('api/v1/locations', true, function (location) {
            location.addRestangularMethod('getLongLat', 'get', 'longlat');
            return location;
        });
    }).service('api/v1/locations');
})
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone was wondering how I resolved this - custom methods alongside a service is actually unsupported in the master branch of Restangular. Calling service will just override the collection and any custom methods applied prior to this with the defaults.

To resolve I've overrided the `toService` function to support custom methods.

Comment: Have you made a pull request for this? Would be really useful to get merged

Comment: Hey David, github link is not working anymore. I need what you have achieved. Could you please update the link?

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore, best to just post the answer on here, so that its always here, cause outside links can disappear.